# Adding a Cordova plugin to iOS project - Cleaver Configuration

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to integrate the PhoneGap WebView i.e. the Cleaver Project in my iOS application. So far I am successful using the stuff but now i want to integrate the plugins that are available for phonegap.

If i do so using the www directory it works fine loading the things up but when I set the directory programmatically then things dont work out nothing gets fired up as the JS files gives the not found exception.

Can someone let me know what is a correct to configure the plugins in cleaver project ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use cleaver, you have to install the plugins using [plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman/)

Comment: Yes I do understand that but I am using a Collection view to select a html folder every time. I am changing the loaded html folder on a user selection.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with cordova 3.x version, try just loading different .html files, all of them on the www folder. With versions previous to 3.x you could do that, but apple won't approve them after february because they don't support 64 bits